# Complex Integral $\int_{C}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I must compute  $\int_{C}\frac{1}{z}dz$ where he branch of $\sqrt{z}$ satisfies $\sqrt{1}=1$.

Where $C$ is a positively oritented semi-cericle $|z|=1$, $0 \leq Arg(z) \leq \pi$.

I am confused on how to satisfy the branch requirement of $\sqrt{z}$. Usually, without branch requirements, I parametrize the contour and continue from there, but with this added requirement I am stuck.

Apparently, this represents $\sqrt{z}$ on the Riemann Surface (which I am not entire sure what that is)[image: $\sqrt{z}$]

Can anyone explain what it means to choose a branch of a function like $\sqrt{z}$? Furthermore, how we satisfy the requirement for the above exercise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "branch", we make a choice as to whether by "1", we mean $e^{i 0}$ or $e^{i 2 \pi}$, for example.  In this case, $\sqrt{e^{i 0}} = e^{i 0} = 1$ while $\sqrt{e^{i 2 \pi}} = e^{i \pi} = -1$.  So, by stating that $\sqrt{1}=1$, the problem means that $1=e^{i 0}$.

Thus, being on a single branch, we may then let $z=e^{i \theta}$, $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, and the integral becomes

$$i \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \, e^{-i \theta/2} = i \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta/2} = 2 \left (e^{i \pi/2} - e^{i 0/2} \right ) = 2 (i-1) $$

NB if we were on the other branch, i.e., $\sqrt{1} = -1 = e^{i \pi}$, then $1=e^{i 2 \pi}$ and we would have as the integral

$$i \int_{2 \pi}^{3 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta/2} = 2 \left (e^{i 3 \pi/2} - e^{i 2 \pi/2} \right ) = 2 (-i +1)$$

Comment: I understand until you begin the integral computations. I agree with the parametrization since $|z|= e^{i t} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)=1$ for $t \in [0, \pi]$. So I do not understand how you form the integrand of $i\int_{0}^{\pi} d\theta e^{i \theta} e^{-i \theta/2}$. Shouldn't we also substitute with $x = \cos(t)$ and $y = \sin(t)$, $dz = dx + idy$?

Comment: @damOhs: what don't you understand about the integral computation?

Comment: $C = |z| = e^{i t} = \underbrace{\cos(t)}_{x(t)} + i \underbrace{\sin(t)}_{y(t)} = 1$ and from what you said, $1 = e^{i 0}$. Then $dz =-\sin(t) + i\cos(t)$ So $$\int_{0}^{\pi} ???$$

Comment: $z=e^{i \theta}$, not $|z|$.  Exponential form is easier to deal with in the integral.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but can you please explain exactly why you wrote $i \int_0^{\pi} d\theta e^{i \theta} e^{- i \theta /2}$? I think we should have  $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(0) + i\sin(0) }} \right )\left ( -\sin(\theta) + i\cos(\theta)\right )d\theta$$

Comment: @damOhs: you are integrating $1/\sqrt{z}$, right?

Comment: Yes. I let $z = e^{i 0} = \cos(0) +i \sin(0)$. I parametrized the contour with $|z| =1$ being equivalent to $e^{i \theta} = \underbrace{\cos(\theta)}_{x} + i\underbrace{\sin(\theta)}_{y} = 1$. Then since $dz = dx + idy$, I obtained the integral above.

Comment: @damOhs: you are really overthinking this.  I think what I laid out is a pretty complete explanation.  The trig representation is simply not convenient here.  And being on a branch does not mean that the function is constant on that branch.  Flush away what you think you know, read the problem and my solution from scratch.  It will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

A branch of $\sqrt z$ is defined whenever you take a slit off the complex plane. In your case, you can consider taking away the slit corresponding to $arg(z)=3\pi/2$. Then your function is defined on a simply connected domain and you can applies the fundamental theorem of calculus. 
\begin{equation}
\int_C \frac{1}{\sqrt z}=-2\sqrt1+2\sqrt{-1}=2(i-1)
\end{equation}

Comment: This would be correct, except it looks like you got the endpoints backward.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks.